# Error in JS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at call.html:10:58"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am new to JavaScript
I am trying to print an array using a function `document.getElementById`
I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at call.html:10:58`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My information</title>
        <body>
            <h1>My name is Luffy</h1>
            <p>I am a software developer</p>
            <script>
            const programmingLanguage = ["Python", "Java","C"];
                document.getElementById("program").innerHTML=programmingLanguage;
            </script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

please help me where did i go wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, you are trying to get an element which has the id program, but there is no element which has the id as `program`.

You can create an element with id `program`.  this will resolve the error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My information</title>
        <body>
            <h1>My name is Luffy</h1>
            <p>I am a software developer</p>
            
            <p id="program"></p>
            
            <script>
            const programmingLanguage = ["Python", "Java","C"];
                document.getElementById("program").innerHTML=programmingLanguage;
            </script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```